# Adding and deleting rows from DataSet concurrently from different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, dataset, locking

I thought I know how `lock` statement works but it seems I don't ... I'm trying to achieve functionality that enables me adding and deleting rows to/from `DataSet` concurrently from separate threads (WinForms project). So one thread is adding new row to `DataSet` every some time interval while other thread is deleting row from the same `DataSet`. I assum that `DataSet` always has some rows to delete - I would like to focus on multithreading issus here. Thread that adds rows to `DataSet` works faster then one that deletes rows. For creating new threads I use `System.Threading.Timer` class which starts new thread while creating new instance on this class. I don't understand why I still get `System.InvalidOperationException` while having `lock` statement in my code. Further message is : "Additional information: Cross thread operation detected."

How should I use `lock` statement ?
Where exactly should I put `lock` statement in my code ?

CODE :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TEST_WinForms
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private const String _strDSname = "dataSet";
    private const String _strTableName = "dtBuffer";

    private object _objLockDataSet = new object();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BuildDataSet()
    {
        DS = new DataSet();
        DS.Tables.Add(_strTableName);

        foreach (DataTable table in DS.Tables)
        {
            table.Columns.Add("LP", typeof(Int32));
            table.Columns.Add("Date and time", typeof(DateTime));
        }
    }

    private void StartT1timer()
    {
        try
        {
            if (T1 == null)
            {
                T1 = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(AddRow)
                                              , null
                                              , 0
                                              , Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            else
            {
                T1.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void StartT2timer()
    {
        try
        {
            if (T2 == null)
            {
                T2 = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(DeleteRow)
                                              , null
                                              , 1000
                                              , Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            else
            {
                T2.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void AddRow(object state)
    {
        lock (_objLockDataSet)
        {
            try
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                {
                    DataRow newRow = DS.Tables[_strTableName].NewRow();

                    if (DS.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        newRow["LP"] =
                            (int)DS.Tables[_strTableName].Rows[DS.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Count - 1]["LP"] + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newRow["LP"] = 1;
                    }

                    newRow["Date and time"] = DateTime.Now;

                    DS.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Add(newRow);

                }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        T1.Change(100, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void DeleteRow(object state)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_objLockDataSet)
            {
                if (DS.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DS.Tables[_strTableName].Rows.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        T2.Change(500, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BuildDataSet();

        gridControl1.DataSource = DS.Tables[_strTableName];

        StartT1timer();

        StartT2timer();
    }

    private DataSet DS
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private System.Threading.Timer T1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private System.Threading.Timer T2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why should it be a `DataTable`? Use one of the [concurrent collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx) provided in .NET

Comment: a dataset can hold a collection of DataTables @dotctor, the problem here is actually when adding Rows it works when deleting rows or columns the op would have to do a for loop using a negative counter, starting from highest to lowest..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `lock` statement, but with accessing UI control (removing rows from data source) from the thread which is not UI thread.

Actually you do it right when adding rows, so do the same when deleting - use form's [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) method in order to execute delegate on the right thread.

Comment: You're right. Adding `Invoke` method in `DeleteRow` method works. I've just checked it. Thanks